# UTF-8 and UTF-8 BOM support in Flyway 7

Tags: flyway

Can anyone validate that UTF-8 BOM encoding is still supported in Flyway 7.x and that setting the flyway encoding to UTF-8 supports both?

Answer (score 0):

Flyway supports both BOM and BOMless UTF8.